# sql - How do I group values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, pivot-table

I have a table so that:

```
> SELECT * FROM tempLog WHERE DATE(ts) = CURDATE() LIMIT 9;

+-------+---------------------+----------+-------+-------+
| id    | ts                  | sensorid | value | event |
+-------+---------------------+----------+-------+-------+
| 11020 | 2017-12-15 00:00:01 |        3 |  18.1 | cron  |
| 11021 | 2017-12-15 00:00:01 |        4 |  14.8 | cron  |
| 11022 | 2017-12-15 00:00:01 |        5 |   1.3 | cron  |
| 11023 | 2017-12-15 00:02:02 |        3 |  18.1 | cron  |
| 11024 | 2017-12-15 00:02:02 |        4 |  14.8 | cron  |
| 11025 | 2017-12-15 00:02:02 |        5 |   1.3 | cron  |
+-------+---------------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

Is it possible to construct a query so i get

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| ts                  | sensor3 | sensor4 | sensor5 |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2017-12-15 00:00:01 |   18.1  |   14.8  |  1.3    |
| 2017-12-15 00:02:02 |   18.1  |   14.8  |  1.3    |
+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

That is, select all different 'time stamps' and get each value from the different sensors at that time.

The sensors will be more at later on, so I would have to take that in account.
They will all be polled at the same 'time stamp'.

Thanks
/jon

Comment: You could use PIVOT in MS SQL:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: If you don't mind getting all sensors in a single column: `select ts, group_concat(concat(' s[',sensorid,']: ',value)) sensors from templog
  group by ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ts, 
       max(case when sensorid = 3 then value else 0 end) as sensor3,
       max(case when sensorid = 4 then value else 0 end) as sensor4,
       max(case when sensorid = 5 then value else 0 end) as sensor5
from your_table
group by ts
```

Comment: I thought of the same thing, but OP said that _The sensors will be more at later on_ so doesn't a loop of some sort would be better (ex. Loop sensorid from 1 to whatever)

Comment: Excellent!
I will construct the sql with some php that takes the number of sensors in account.
The max(case solved it.
/jon